# How to hide row in the rtf template for oracle fusion by condition? and what is this markup language named?

Tags: xml, oracle, rtf, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-fusion-apps

I have rtf template made for oracle fusion app

[image]

when I upload it do app, when I upload it there, I get such data:

[image]

I need to get: Line should not be shown if balance column amount is zero

How to do it using RTF MARKING LANGUAGE(without limiting the request to sql)? How is it language called correctly and where I can find whole docs?
I have found and read this but this is not all that need:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/bip/BIPRD/GUID-04477E49-F671-4BF1-8353-06A7CDEAD2CC.htm#BIPRD2500

I tried to write this, but it not works.
`<?if@row:BAL_AMT='0'?>attribute@type="PRIVATE"<?end if?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the link below for solution:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10091_01/doc/bip.1013/b40017/T421739T481157.htm

***Conditionally Displaying a Row***

To display only rows that meet a certain condition, insert the   tags at the beginning and end of the row, within the for-each tags for the group.

Note the following fields from the sample figure:

Default Text Entry      Form FieldHelp Text    Description

**for-each SALE**                 Opens the for-each loop to repeat the data belonging to the SALE group.

**if big**                  5000?>       If statement to display the row only if the element SALES has a value greater than 5000.

**SALES end if**                          Closes the if statement.

**end SALE**                        Closes the SALE loop.